# Node module; Mongod not returning promise at all?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules

I'm using [mongod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongod)
module to start a MongoDB server for my node.js app. 
 I'm quite new to programming and after some googling I think it is the best I could come up with.

In **mongod documentation**, `Mongod#open()` returns a promise, which I believe I consume correctly.

> **However, my code never gets to the point where the client connects and I can't spot what I did wrong.**

*Here's my code:*

```
const
    Mongod = require('mongod'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    config = require('./config');

const
    mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/' + config.db.table_name,
    server = new Mongod({
        conf: config.db.path_to_cfg
    });

const connectToDB = (uri) => {
    return MongoClient.connect(uri);
};

//If mongod service is not running, create a new server and connect
console.log(server.isRunning); //Just to verify



 if (!server.isRunning) {
        console.log('dbConnect:: Starting MongoDB server...');
        server.open()
            .then(() => {
                connectToDB(mongoURI)
                    .then((db) => {
                        console.log(db)
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log('Error: ' + err)
                    })
            })
    } else {
        connectToDB(mongoURI)
            .then((db) => {
                console.log(db)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Error: ' + err)
            })
    }
```

> *dbConnect:: Starting MongoDB server...* logs in the console, the server runs successfully, since I can connect from windows CLI and query the database, but .then() is not executed and db is not logged.

I have tested the **else block** it is working as it should, (which also means my **config** module is correct) logging the db object when I have previously started the server from CLI.

Comment: Are you sure `MongoClient.connect(uri);` returns a Promise ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, it's in the driver documentation plus I can see the connection  to the db server in the command line when *else* executes. I just copy-pasted the same block in if-else to test that. If a solution is found I'll move it to the connectToDB() function.

Comment: @ArisKonstantoulas Does the promise returned from `server.open` actually successfully resolve? You're not attaching any reject handler to it.

Comment: I will test it to the best of my abilities right now. I think it does, since the server indeed starts.

Comment: @Jiří Pospíšil I did attach a    .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
I don't get any output, I guess it resolves

PS: I can't edit my previous comment.